# mysql wait_timeout exceeds

Tags: mysql

Hi Any body please tell me , my application has 10 processes , all processes are connects to DB for getting customers details.and my DB wait_timeout value is 30 sec. what will happen when my application is sleep more than wait_timeout value ?

Answer (score 0):

You will get `MySQL server has gone away` if `wait_timeout` exceeds.
I think you can use auto reconnect option in your application refer
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/auto-reconnect.html